# C# razor - foreach - group together items with same category and wrap a div around them

Tags: c#, razor

My model has a Category and Name value, and I want to group together all items that have same category value

```
foreach(var item in Model){
    <div class="@Model.Category">@Model.Name</div>
}
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
<div class="group-category-1">
    <div class="category-1">Name 1</div>
    <div class="category-1">Name 2</div>
    <div class="category-1">Name 3</div>
</div>

<div class="group-category-2">
    <div class="category-2">Name 1</div>
    <div class="category-2">Name 2</div>
    <div class="category-3">Name 3</div>
</div>

<div class="group-category-3">
    <div class="category-3">Name 1</div>
    <div class="category-3">Name 2</div>
    <div class="category-3">Name 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try grouping by category and then filtering each category's items for each category.

```
@{
  var categories = Model.GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
  foreach(var category in categories ) {
    var categoryItems = Model.Where(x => x.Category == category.Category);
    <div class="group-@category.Category">
    foreach(var item in categoryItems){
      <div class="@category.Category">@item.Name</div>
    }
    </div>
  }
}
```